# std::apply emplace_back with a parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

I am trying to emplace a new object into a container inside a template function. Since the template function receives an std::tuple with the arguments needed to create the object, I am using std::apply and a fold expression to unpack the tuple values. However, it doesn't compile

My code is equivalent to

```
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    S(float restAngle, bool useIt) 
      : restAngle(restAngle)
      , useIt(useIt)
    {}
    float restAngle;
    bool useIt;
};


int main()
{
    std::tuple t(0.0F, false);
    std::vector<S> ss;
    std::apply([&ss](auto ...data) {ss.emplace_back((data,...));}, t);
}
```

and it fails with the following compilation error in gcc 13

```
n file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/vector:63,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = S; _Args = {bool&}; _Tp = S]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:537:17:   required from 'static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::construct(allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = S; _Args = {bool&}; _Tp = S; allocator_type = std::allocator<S>]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/vector.tcc:117:30:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {bool&}; _Tp = S; _Alloc = std::allocator<S>; reference = S&]'
<source>:18:52:   required from 'main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)> [with auto:1 = {float, bool}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/type_traits:2558:26:   required by substitution of 'template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> static std::__result_of_success<decltype (declval<_Fn>()((declval<_Args>)()...)), std::__invoke_other> std::__result_of_other_impl::_S_test(int) [with _Fn = main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)>; _Args = {float&, bool&}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/type_traits:2569:55:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/type_traits:161:35:   recursively required by substitution of 'template<class _Result, class _Ret> struct std::__is_invocable_impl<_Result, _Ret, true, std::__void_t<typename _CTp::type> > [with _Result = std::__invoke_result<main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)>, float&, bool&>; _Ret = void]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/type_traits:161:35:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Bn> std::__detail::__first_t<std::integral_constant<bool, true>, typename std::enable_if<(bool)(_Bn::value), void>::type ...> std::__detail::__and_fn(int) [with _Bn = {std::__is_invocable_impl<std::__invoke_result<main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)>, float&, bool&>, void, true, void>, std::__call_is_nothrow<std::__invoke_result<main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)>, float&, bool&>, main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)>, float&, bool&>}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/type_traits:177:42:   required from 'struct std::__and_<std::__is_invocable_impl<std::__invoke_result<main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)>, float&, bool&>, void, true, void>, std::__call_is_nothrow<std::__invoke_result<main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)>, float&, bool&>, main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)>, float&, bool&> >'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/type_traits:3103:12:   required from 'struct std::is_nothrow_invocable<main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)>, float&, bool&>'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/tuple:2272:31:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__unpack_std_tuple<template<class _Fn, class ... _ArgTypes> struct std::is_nothrow_invocable, main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)>, std::tuple<float, bool>&>'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/tuple:2295:14:   required from 'constexpr decltype(auto) std::apply(_Fn&&, _Tuple&&) [with _Fn = main()::<lambda(auto:1 ...)>; _Tuple = tuple<float, bool>&]'
<source>:18:15:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:187:11: error: no matching function for call to 'S::S(bool&)'
  187 |         { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:5:5: note: candidate: 'S::S(float, bool)'
    5 |     S(float restAngle, bool useIt)
      |     ^
<source>:5:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
<source>:3:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr S::S(const S&)'
    3 | struct S
      |        ^
<source>:3:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'bool' to 'const S&'
<source>:3:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr S::S(S&&)'
<source>:3:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'bool' to 'S&&'
```

I can't find what is wrong with the code. Apparently is trying to call the emplace_back with just the `bool` arguments, which I don't understand. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: `ss.emplace_back(data,...)`?

Comment: Simple typo: https://godbolt.org/z/dhP764hq9

Comment: afaik, that is not valid C++, the fold expression must be inside parenthesis

Comment: @jjcasmar You don't want a fold expression, you want pack expansion.

Comment: You are right, I didn't need a fold expression

Answer (score 3):

You have the syntax a little off.  In

```
ss.emplace_back((data,...))
```

You are using a fold expression of the comma operator on the pack of `data` so it expands out to

```
ss.emplace_back((data1, data2, ..., dataN))
```

and since it is the comma operator only `dataN` is returned from the inner parentheses which in your case is the `bool` object of the tuple.  To get all of the pack in the call to `emplace_back` you just need

```
ss.emplace_back(data...)
```

which expands to

```
ss.emplace_back(data1, data2, ..., dataN)
```

which is how the call to `emplace_back` should look like.

Comment: omg, I thought I needed a fold expression. Thanks!

Comment: @jjcasmar No worries.  A simple way to remember which to use is that a fold expression acts on each member of a parameter pack.  Pack expansion just expands the pack out separated by comas for passing to things.